# MacInCloud - Deploy existing React Project

Tags: macos, mac-in-cloud

I have developed my **React** application on **Windows 10**, and wish to publish it to the IOS Apple Store. Could I transfer my entire project files from my local windows pc to the macincloud environment for the purpose of publishing it?  Would I also be able to successfully signup to apple developer program using the macincloud environment? Thanks.